# mySQL, multiple joins on same table with different criteria. Rename columns at query

Tags: mysql, join

Greetings and thank you for reading my question.

First up, the graphic below depicts part of a database I am creating. My goal (unless there is any better way to do this) is to support multiple languages for fields which would normally be called something like "schedule_name" and "schedule_description" in to a seperate table. P.S - I know the column types in this diagram are labelled badly.

[image: database]

As you can see, boat, cruise and schedule each have a languageid as foreign key. If I want to pull out the schedule record with cruise and boat, how would I go about this please?

I have the tables joined no problem, column alias' sorted but, would like to get the correct details in to each alias. For clarity

Schedule has it's own language_language_id reference to pick out
using language_id = 1
language_name_en is - Monday Morning

Cruise has it's own language_language_id reference to pick out
using language_id = 2
language_name_en is - Sunny Haze

Boat has it's own language_language_id reference to pick out
using language_id = 3
language_name_en is - Blue Dolphin

Answering a comment to this question; en is for english, zhs for simplfied chinese and zht for traditional Chinese. These are the languages this system is to support for dynamic data. I thought it would be convenient to lay out the tables like this so there can be a user type who is only responsible for dealing with language; no need to deal with the scheduling table.

So far, I believe my query would go as follows to attain a sample record as shown afterwards:

```
SELECT 
   schedule_id,
   s.language_name_en as schedule_name_en,
   l.language_name_zhs as schedule_name_zhs,
   l.language_name_zht as schedule_name_zht,
   schedulesafename,
   schedule_expected_arrival,
   schedule_expected_departure,
   cruise_id,
   c.language_name_en as cruise_name_en,
   c.language_name_zhs as cruise_name_zhs,
   c.language_name_zht as cruise_name_zht 
   FROM
      schedule as s 
   INNER JOIN
      language as l 
         ON s.language_language_id = l.language_id
   INNER JOIN
      cruise as c
         ON c.language_language_id = l.language_id
   Where
      schedule_id = 1;
```

Here is some sample data for what I want returned using the query listed.

```
scheduleid - 1
schedule_name_en - monday morning
schedule_name_zhs - 星期一的早晨
schedule_name_zht - 星期一的早晨
schedule_safename - pwupglfkpmwcbkgzhmzxrqfeqzlhvaed 
schedule_expected_arrival - 1353138308
schedule_expected_departure - 1353139218
cruise_id - 1 
cruise_name_en - Sunny Haze
cruise_name_zhs - 彩霞
cruise_name_zht - 彩霞
cruise_safename - bbhdrunzdmftyvhprefvogysgfrtnkgm
```

This gives you an idea of how I would want to grab the data from the database. My main problem being how to rip out the language records in the same query. Thank you kindly for reading my question.

Comment: Just to add a little scope to my question which i missed to clear up some abiguity. I am also familiar with column renaming at run time and will add a quick query of how i believe things should be

Comment: After doing some more research, I have come across the prospect of using subqueries to achieve the feat. I believe using subqueries confuses the optimiser though?

Comment: I don't think subqueries confuse the optimizer. But your question confuses me. I'm not sure what your question is, really. You want to know how to make column alias? Or what?

Comment: @Buttle Butkus - Thank you for the reply. Sorry for the confusion. What I want is as follows; I will also update the main question after. schedule has a unique language_id to reference. cruise has a unique language_id to reference. Boat has a unique language_id to reference. How to join these individually?

Comment: Please re-edit your question, and at the bottom of it, show some sample data from the respective tables.  It APPEARS that each record (ex: schedule) table has a Language ID record which points to its own one language record with two column basis of name and description in the "name"d language.  Then another language ID for the cruise, and another for the boat... I guess to get the respective "description" of those per language too.  Finally, what are _zhs and _zht with respect to language -- should see in data samples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are very close, you just need to re-use the same language table with different alias for the respective table it is going for... something like

```
SELECT 
      S.schedule_id,
      SL.language_name_en as schedule_name_en,
      SL.language_name_zhs as schedule_name_zhs,
      SL.language_name_zht as schedule_name_zht,
      schedulesafename,
      S.schedule_expected_arrival,
      S.schedule_expected_departure,
      C.cruise_id,
      CL.language_name_en as cruise_name_en,
      CL.language_name_zhs as cruise_name_zhs,
      CL.language_name_zht as cruise_name_zht 
   FROM
      schedule as s 
         INNER JOIN language as SL 
            ON s.language_language_id = SL.language_id
         INNER JOIN cruise as c
            on s.Cruise_Cruise_ID = c.Cruise_Id
            INNER JOIN language as CL 
               ON c.language_language_id = CL.language_id
   Where
      S.schedule_id = 1;
```

Notice first, the Schedule (alias S) joined to language (first time is aliased as "SL" for Schedule Language ) on the schedules language ID join.

Next, the schedule joins to the CRUISE on the Cruise ID.

Finally, the CRUISE table is joined to the language table (this time is aliased "CL" for the Cruise Language ) by the CRUISE language ID value.

So you now have the same table source twice, each for the respective "Language ID" elements you are trying to pull out.

Comment: I feel enlightened, thank you, your answer is very much appreciated. We learn something new everyday. It works swiftly. Your explanation is very clear, better than the SQL explain.

Comment: @SimonBall, glad to help.  As you already had a descent format to your SQL, notice how my version shows the nested relation between each source to the next table... then from schedule to cruise to language for cruise... that is indented under the language... Helps keep things oriented to WHERE am I getting things from.